# Automatically write email attachments to disk

Tags: email, automation, cloud

I have a service that generates a .csv file and emails it to me on regular intervals. I need an automated method for saving the attachment to local disk. **I would need the 'local copy' of the .csv to be overwritten by the latest version each time a new email comes in.** Right now the emails are coming into a gmail account but I could use something different if needed. I have found some google drive apps but not one that will overwrite the file each time. I have to think someone is doing something like this already somewhere. Can anyone offer a solution for accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you have gmail, I found [this reference](https://lifehacker.com/automatically-save-gmail-attachments-to-google-drive-wi-510450340) that has one possible way. There were two other listings at the top of [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+save+incoming+attachment+automatically&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I've NOT used these myself, but HTH.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have actually already tried the app you referenced. It works except it keeps rereading all the previous files in the mail box dispite having filters set up not to do so. I had purchased it and paid for support. Opened a support ticket with the developer but got no response. So I'm trying to find another solution. I have tried 4 or 5 different google apps so far.